# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) python web2py

Tags: python, mysql, web2py, dateadd

The code below is giving me the following error: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Row'`

```
import datetime
#product withholding in days
days = (0)

pdays = db(db.product.withholding_period>0).select().first()

wdate = db(db.stock_task.completed_date>0).select().first()

fdate = wdate + datetime.timedelta(days+pdays)
```

Can anyone explain what causes this error and how it can be solved?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are trying to add up `days` (which is int) and `pdays` (which is Row). the `+` operator does not work with these two type of arguments

Comment: so I need to the value of the pdays?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a database Row to an int. You need to extract the `pdays` and `wdate` from the correct column in the row. Swap the column names below with the correct ones for your table:

```
import datetime

product withholding in days

days = (0)

# get the pdays
pdays_row = db(db.product.withholding_period>0).select().first()
pdays = pdays_row.withholding_period

# get the wdate
wdate_row = db(db.stock_task.completed_date>0).select().first()
wdate = wdate_row.completed_ date

fdate = wdate + datetime.timedelta(days + pdays)
```

Comment: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>()

Comment: what is the column name where the wdate or pdays value is stored, and what is the data type of that column?

Comment: pdays is withholding_period

Comment: ok so that should be fine with my updated answer...and what is the column name of the wdate value you want?

Comment: wdate is completed_ date value of date  fdate goes to withhold_until and is a date field

Comment: do I have to store pdays and wdate into a table ??

Comment: no as long as you can access the date in the way you want then you should be fine (but it does depend on how you want to use and access the data)...updated the answer with column names

Comment: wdate = wdate_row.completed_date
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'completed_date'

Comment: so possibly wdate_row is returning None - what's the result of the wdate_row query?

Comment: thanks for your help but think I need to rethink the the way I am doing it

Comment: if anyone thinks this is possible feel free to comment